# Blue card rejection because of not having a Masters degree certificate at hand

Tags: germany, working-visas, eu, blue-card

I completed my Masters (IT) from Germany some weeks ago. By completion, I mean I got the grades of my final thesis. But the actual physical copy of the masters degree certificate will take some time to arrive (maybe a few months). Since I got a job offer starting from June, I applied for EU Blue card. But I received a **rejection** today saying that they need the degree certificate as that is a criteria for the Blue card application. During my application, I had provided a letter from my university stating that *I have passed all my courses and the final certificate will take a few weeks to be prepared*. I guess the letter was not enough to prove that I have passed my degree program and graduated.

Has anyone faced a similar issue? Can anyone please help as to why this might have happened?

Comment: isn't a bachelor's degree also sufficient for a blue card?

Comment: Where exactly in Germany this happened? (i.e. which German state?), because as far as I know, the letter should be enough, assuming it was written by the appropriate authority in your Uni (the program director). Please add all relevant details.

Comment: @user253751 I didn't submit my bachelor's degree because my job is based on my master's program (IT). My bachelors was in Electrical engineering.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I am in Bavaria. I also thought the same. The letter was from my Masters program coordinators. They are the one responsible for the academic-related requests/queries.

Comment: I suggest to ask them, they probably know what to do, its likely to be a mistake in the migration office. My experience is in NRW where I had many students use this kind of letter to obtain a new residence permit.

Comment: Did you reapply after you received your degree? I have the same situation.. University provided a letter stating that I completed my studies and issuance of degree will take some time. I wanted to apply Blue card with this letter but now I doubt it… @Alex

Answer (score 0):

@Dr.Snoopy -- no, this is not correct.  I had such a letter submitted, and I received notification (also in NRW, in Aachen in 2019) that they would not issue my Blue Card until I had the certificate at hand.  So I had to wait until my certificate was available, and delay the start of my assignment by more than 2 months, before the Blue Card was issued.  So yes, this situation is within norms.